# ngFor JSON array of object async await angular 13 not binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

Here is my *typescript* page.

```
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any;
  constructor(){}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.loadUser();
  }

  async loadUser() {
      const us = this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
       first(),
      catchError((errorMessage) => {
        return of(EMPTY_UserProfile);
      })
).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.users = data;
  console.log(this.users);
});
this.subscriptions.push(us);
  }
}
```

As the `this.user` bind easily, it gives me result as

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "xyz",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "xyz2",
  }
]
```

Here is the HTML *ngFor*.

```
<tr align="center" *ngFor="let user of users | async; let i=index">
     <td>{{user.id}}</td>
     <td>{{user.userName}} </td>
</tr>
```

There is no output shown as I tried every possible way I found through articles. It works when I try to call a fixed **Array JSON object** in the **constructor** but calling `async` `await` in `ngOnInit` doesn't really help me.
I might be missing something?

**Update 1:**

Here is the observable part where service is being called.

```
    getUsers(id?: string): Observable<UserDetails> {
    const auth = this.getAuthFromLocalStorage();
    if (!auth || !auth.authToken) {
      return of(undefined);
    }

    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);
    return this.userHttpService.getUsers(auth.authToken, '').pipe(
      map((user: UserDetails) => {
        if (user) {
          this.currentUsers = new BehaviorSubject<UserDetails>(user);
        } else {
          this.logout();
        }
        return user;
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }
```

**Update 2:**
this calls from Update 1 as `this.userHttpService.getUsers(auth.authToken, '')`

```
getUsers(token, Id?: string): Observable<UserDetails> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    });
    return this.http.get<UserDetails>(`${API_URL}/GetCompanyUsers?Id=` + Id + `&pageNumber=1` + `&pageSize=1`, {
      headers: httpHeaders,
    });
  }
```

Comment: @GRD cause I'm calling a HTTP request

Comment: There is not any need to async await, you can do http call without it.

Comment: so getUsers and getUserProfile both are different method ?

Comment: Observables ≠ Promises. You *do not* need to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) when using observables. Also the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) you used in the HTML is not the same as the Javascript `async`. Rule of thumb: Subscription to an observable in the TS file and `async` pipe in the HTML file are mutually exclusive. You only need to use one of them on an observable. Not both.

Comment: @NamanKumar for inner observable you can use mergeMap or concateMap rxjs operator too, this will ease your calling of subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here.

1. No need to add async await here as GRD also said in the comment.
2. you already subscribing so no need to use the async pipe.

Note: if you are directly using observable then use async pipe.

```
  users: any[] = [];
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  loadUser() {
      const sb = this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
       first(),
       catchError((errorMessage) => {
        return of(EMPTY_UserProfile);
       })
      ).subscribe((users: UserProfile[]) => {
      this.users = users; //data is recieved but not shown on ngFor HTML page
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(sb);
  }
}
```

```
<tr align="center" *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
     <td>{{user.id}}</td>
     <td>{{user.userName}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: there is observable involved in this I'll give an update for this as well on question.

Comment: userService.getUserProfile returns observable, that you are already subscribing and assigning the result in users property. Other than that is there any other observable involved?

Comment: this.userHttpService.getUsers(auth.authToken, '') this also calls Observable which binds in the model I've updated the questions with new update

Comment: Sorry wrong update will rectify

Comment: Still, there is no other observable involved, you are just returning it from one method(level) to another. and at the end subscribing to your component.

Comment: I found out that after using menu routing to reach this page the list appears but when I reload the page with F5 it doesn't show, so the answer is correct as above and which I was doing with Array<any> also shows the result with routing but page reload does not help load it.

Comment: It depends where you are persisting(if) the menu-item on UI(service instance or local/session storage). Try to refresh menu on every hard reload. But I can't see any menu-related thing in this question, so please ask a new question with details.

Answer (score 0):

As the **async** pipe definition states

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted.

You'll need to apply **async** pipe, if you are binding to an observable, in your case in the **loadUser()** method you are **subscribing** to an observable and hence no need to use **async** pipe.

If you want to apply **async** pipe, then modify the **loadUser** method like this

```
  loadUser():Observable<any[]> {
  const sb = this.userService.getUserProfile().pipe(
   first(),
   catchError((errorMessage) => {
    return of(EMPTY_UserProfile);
   })
  );
this.subscriptions.push(sb);
return sb;
 }
```

and then you'll have to modify the *ngFor like this

```
<tr align="center" *ngFor="let user of loadUser() | async; let i=index">
 <td>{{user.id}}</td>
 <td>{{user.userName}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Binding a function to a directive like `*ngFor` with default change detection strategy will trigger the function multiple times (essentially a trigger for each change detection cycle) which could like to performance issues later down the road.

Comment: yeah agreed, just for a demonstration purpose that async pipe is only applicable on observables (or promises)